# How do I get sbt to not try to compile a directory whose name ends in .scala as a Scala source file?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to convert an existing **Maven** multi-module project over to use **sbt** instead. One of the module subdirectories has `.scala` at the end of its name (because it's a pure Scala implementation of a library that was originally written in Java). **Maven** had no problem with this. However, **sbt** sees the `.scala` and thinks that the directory is a Scala source file and tries to compile it, which fails, of course.

How can I configure **sbt** so that it doesn't try to compile a directory as a source file? Note that the top-level (root) project doesn't contain any source code itself, so disabling compilation altogether at that level would be an acceptable solution (as long as it doesn't prevent the submodules from being compiled).

Yes, I have considered simply renaming the submodule directory so that it doesn't contain `.scala`, but I would prefer to avoid restructuring my build tree if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say the name of your directory is `./directory.scala` (located in the root of the project).  Then this should do the trick:

```
excludeFilter in Compile := "directory.scala"
```